# Find pmf of the function $Y(t)=rect(t-.5-D)$ where $D$ is uniform over (0,1)

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

The random process with $Y(t)=rect(t-.5-D)$ where $D$ is uniform over (0,1)
Find its probability mass function.What do I with the uniform stuff in the rect function?

So $f_D(d)=d$ for $0<d<1$ and 0 elsewhere. So the pmf should be:
$f_{Y(t)}y(t)=rect(t-.5-d)$ for $0<d<1$ and 0 elsewhere. Does it look right?

Comment: How exactly are you defining "Rect"?

Comment: rect(t-0.5)=1 if 0<t<1 o elsewhere